# ‎$ ‎\theta‎$‎-‎closed set

Tags: general-topology

‎Let ‎$  ‎X‎$‎ be a space, and ‎$  ‎B‎$‎ a ‎subset. ‎‎$‎  x ‎\in X‎$ ‎is ‎‎‎‎defined to be a ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-limit point of ‎$  ‎B‎$‎ iff every closed nhood of ‎$  ‎x‎$ ‎intersects ‎$ ‎B‎ $‎‎‎‎ . ‎$  ‎B‎$‎ is said to be ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-‎closed ‎iff it contains all of its ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-limit ‎points.‎

**‎Lemma.** Let ‎$  ‎M‎$‎ be a subspace of the space ‎$  ‎X‎$‎.

(1) If ‎$ X‎ ‎‎\setminus M‎ ‎‎ $‎ is ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-closed in ‎$  ‎X‎$‎, then ‎$ ‎cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(M)‎ ‎\setminus ‎M‎ $ ‎is‎‎  ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-closed in ‎$ ‎cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(X)‎ ‎\setminus ‎M‎ $‎.‎

(2) If ‎$  ‎M‎$‎ is open and ‎$ ‎cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(M)‎ ‎\setminus ‎M ‎ =‎ ‎bd‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(M)‎$‎ is ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-closed in ‎$ ‎cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎‎(M)‎‎‎ $‎ , then
‎$  X‎ ‎‎\setminus ‎M‎‎ $‎ is ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-closed in ‎$  ‎X‎$‎.

- ‎A subset S of a space ‎‎$‎(X, ‎\tau‎)‎‎$‎ is said to be quasi H-closed ‎subset ‎(resp. ‎subspace)‎ if for every cover ‎‎$ ‎\{ ‎V_i : i ‎\in ‎\alpha \}  ‎\subset ‎\tau‎$ ‎(resp.‎ ‎$ ‎\subset ‎\tau‎_{‎S }‎‎$)‎  ‎of ‎‎‎‎$‎S‎$‎ ‎‎‎, there exists a finite subset ‎$ ‎\alpha‎_{‎0‎}‎‎ ‎\subset‎ ‎‎\alpha‎‎‎‎ $‎ such that $ S ‎‎\subset ‎\bigcup‎_{‎i \in ‎\alpha‎_{0}‎‎‎}‎ cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(V_i)‎‎‎‎‎$ ( ‎resp. ‎$  S ‎‎\subset ‎\bigcup‎_{‎i \in ‎\alpha‎_{0}‎‎‎}‎ cl‎_{‎\tau‎_{‎S‎}‎‎}‎(V_i)‎$‎‎)‎.
  ‎
- A space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be locally quasi H-closed space  if each point if X has a $\tau$ -open
  neighbourhood which is a quasi H-closed subspace of $(X, \tau)$. Each quasi H-closed space is locally quasi H-closed, the converse is not true.

**My question:**

*‎Let ‎‎$‎(‎ X,\tau) $‎‎ be ‎quasi‎ H-closed and ‎$  ‎B‎$‎ an open subset. ‎$  ‎B‎$‎ is ‎locally ‎qhasi ‎H-closed‎  **iff** ‎$  X ‎‎\setminus B ‎‎‎$‎ is a ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎-closed subset of ‎$  ‎X‎$‎ **iff** ‎$ Bd‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(‎B)‎ $‎‎‎‎ is a ‎$ ‎\theta‎ $‎-closed subset of ‎$ ‎cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(B)‎ $ ‎‎.‎
‎*

**the Proof of one side:** ‎‎$  ‎B‎$‎ is ‎locally ‎qhasi ‎H-‎closed.‎ Let ‎$  ‎b‎$‎ be an element of the ‎locally ‎qhasi ‎H-‎closed‎ ‎space ‎$  ‎B‎$‎. Since ‎$  ‎B‎$‎ is ‎locally ‎qhasi ‎H-‎closed‎, there exists some qhasi ‎H-‎closed‎ nhood of ‎$  ‎b‎$‎ contained in ‎$  ‎B‎$‎ , and this closed nhood is disjoint from $ X‎ ‎‎\setminus ‎B  ‎$‎, which is therefore ‎$  ‎\theta‎$‎‎‎-‎closed.‎

Is the other direction correct?

‎

Comment: The backslash means "not including" right?  Like subtracting sets?  A\B = A-B?

Comment: yes, it means A - B.